# Discord.js sending message upon voice channel joining is not working

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

so what my bot is meant to do is that when someone joins a certain channel, it will send a message to log channel "SomeGuy123 joined the channel!". So I was constructing it for like an hour, and now I resolved all the errors, but it doesnt say anything, nor it doesnt give any errors. I can send the whole code if you want. Here is just the part about sending the message upon joining:

```
  client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
  const newUserChannel = newState.ChannelID;
  const oldUserChannel = oldState.ChannelID
  const textChannel = newState.guild.channels.cache.get('715141269395079208')

  if(newUserChannel === '715141827644358707') {
    textChannel.send(`${newState.user.username} (${newState.id}) has joined the channel`)
  } else if (oldUserChannel === '715141827644358707' && newUserChannel !== '715141827644358707') {
    textChannel.send(`${newState.user.username} (${newState.id}) has left the channel`)
  }
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState

`<VoiceState>.ChannelID` is undefined, its `<VoiceState>.channelID`, javascript is not pascal case except in classes